# There is a display issue I am getting in oxygen editor woo commerce image getting cut only in Mozilla Firefox not sure why?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a website in oxygen and I made single page template for woocommerce. I am creating a custom layout in oxygen builder. I notice one of my Product links http://carolinecunningham.com.dedi963.jnb3.host-h.net/shop/art-of-caroline/gifts/books-gifts/seven-cs-to-calm-reclaiming-your-anxiety-free-self-book/ the product image is kind of cutting from the right side. I tried with many width setting to 100% but nothing seems to help.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why did you tag your question with [eclipse] (how is your issue related to Eclipse)? I know more than one software called Oxygen. Could you please link to which one you mean exactly?

Comment: This one https://oxygenbuilder.com/ sorry I was new here and I get the suggestion of eclipse so I add